# Why can't I save the numeric value of errno?

Tags: c, c99, errno

I tried to save the value of *errno* for later evaluation,
but failed:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void main(void)
{

  int read_errno;

  /* read() operation sets errno */
  read(...);
  read_errno = errno;
  printf("errno was %s\n", strerror(errno));
  printf("errno was %s\n", strerror(read_errno));
}
```

Here the results was:

```
errno was Stream ioctl timeout
errno was Success
```

Why can't I save the numeric value of *errno* to the variable *read_errno*?

Comment: You printed `strerror(errno)` twice, not `strerror(read_errno)`.

Comment: Your program never uses the value `read_errno` so it is not clear how you are concluding that it was not set correctly. Can you explain further what you expected to see and why/

Comment: Ah, sorry, it now uses `read_errno` in the second call to `printf()`.

Comment: Pretty sure you need to include `<string.h>` to use `strerror`.

Comment: If you are still having trouble, please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: The code that is currently in your question works for me: https://onlinegdb.com/n9CtXiwhm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to `printf` or possibly `strerror` itself reset* the `errno` variable so the second `printf`  prints the result of the first one, not `read`. Good practice is to save it as soon as possible, before any other function call.

Correct example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    errno=EPERM; // An example
    int read_errno = errno;
    printf("errno was %s\n", strerror(read_errno));
    printf("errno was %s\n", strerror(read_errno));
}
```

Output:

```
errno was Operation not permitted
errno was Operation not permitted
```

*They do not have to reset it, furthermore successfull call to `strerror` must not modify it.

Comment: Even if I switched the order so that I saved `errno`to `read_errno` before calling `printf()`, I got the same result...

Comment: @LukesDiner Added a correct example.

Comment: @Quimby shouldn't te second printf print `strerror(errno)` instead of `strerror(read_errno)`?

Comment: @Jabberwocky Well, the original question was why the second identical `printf` prints a different value. I answered that it is because of modification done to the `errno`. My corrected code correctly prints the same message two times. So no, it is intentional. The question has been now modified and also shows a correct code, which makes it confusing.